# bond eth0 and wlan0 on combine mode

Tags: pi-3, networking

I'm rewriting my original question as I could advance on my issue.

I'm trying to bond eth0 + wifi on some combine mode to improve transfer rate on with my raspberry pi 3. After reading those docs below I got it to work partially.

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/bonding.html
- cat /usr/share/doc/ifenslave/examples/ethernet+hotplug_wifi

**Issues:**

1. I want to combine those interfaces but they are working on some kind of fault tolerance only.
2. Booting is taking too long
3. Only wifi interface is connecting on boot time
4. Ethernet interface once up works but alone, I'm assuming it due speedtest results.

**My config:**

**pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet dhcp
        bond-slaves eth0 wlan0
        bond-mode 0
        bond-miimon 100
        #bond-primary eth0
        post-up route add default gw 192.168.1.1 bond0
        pre-down route del default gw 192.168.1.1 bond0

# auto eth0
# iface eth0 inet manual
#       bond-master bond0
#       bond-mode 0

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
        bond-master bond0
        bond-mode 0
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-give-a-chance 10
        wpa-bridge bond0
        wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

*Uncommenting eth0 interface I got no network at all*

**pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ ifconfig**

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.142  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6d93:61a8:77cf:7485  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a0c:5a80:1b05:8900:cd59:ab7a:fed7:2ca6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 135443  bytes 127519700 (121.6 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90394  bytes 77189328 (73.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.142  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::6d93:61a8:77cf:7485  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 103684  bytes 103257937 (98.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 43267  bytes 35431464 (33.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 272  bytes 27315 (26.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 272  bytes 27315 (26.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.215.153.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.215.153.1
        inet6 fd11:5ee:bad:c0de::1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 1000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.142  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::c930:5fe9:1f4b:3e38  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 31859  bytes 24271757 (23.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 47216  bytes 41767893 (39.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

*All the 3 interfaces bond0, eth0 and wlan0 have the same mac address that is the eth0 one.*

*The ip 192.168.1.142 is the ip reversed on my ISP router for eth0 mac address*

Some other important settings:

**pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ uname -a**

```
Linux rpi-vpn 5.15.76-v7+ #1597 SMP Fri Nov 4 12:13:17 GMT 2022 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ lsmod | grep bonding**

```
bonding               147456  0
```

**pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ systemctl status wpa_supplicant**

```
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ systemctl status dhcpcd.service
● dhcpcd.service - DHCP Client Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
             └─wait.conf
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-12-29 08:23:11 GMT; 17min ago
       Docs: man:dhcpcd(8)
    Process: 367 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/dhcpcd -w -q (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1596)
        CPU: 4.314s
     CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
             ├─568 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
             └─763 /usr/sbin/dhcpcd -w -q

Dec 29 08:28:05 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: carrier acquired
Dec 29 08:28:05 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: IAID eb:4c:42:ef
Dec 29 08:28:05 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: IAID conflicts with one assigned to wlan0
Dec 29 08:28:05 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: adding address fe80::6d93:61a8:77cf:7485
Dec 29 08:28:05 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Dec 29 08:28:06 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.1.142
Dec 29 08:28:06 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: probing address 192.168.1.142/24
Dec 29 08:28:11 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: leased 192.168.1.142 for infinity
Dec 29 08:28:11 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.1.0/24
Dec 29 08:28:11 rpi-vpn dhcpcd[763]: eth0: adding default route via 192.168.1.1
```

**pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ route -n**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 bond0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.215.153.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 bond0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

All the tests below were ran without change anything it just seems the first one was wifi only and the last one ethernet only.

**pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ speedtest**

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from XXX (x)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by XXX (xxx) [2.00 km]: 30.684 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 9.20 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 11.54 Mbit/s
```

**pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ speedtest**

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration... 
Testing from XXX (x)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list... 
Selecting best server based on ping... 
Hosted by XXXXX (xxxx) [0.88 km]: 29.03 ms 
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 51.62 Mbit/s 
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 37.49 Mbit/s
```

**pi@rpi-vpn:~ $ speedtest**

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from xxx (xxx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by XXXXX (xxxx) [2.00 km]: 29.093 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 78.98 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
```

Comment: You should indicate whether or not you have disabled dhcpcd, which runs by default on RpiOS and will screw up or be screwed up by use of ifup and /etc/interfaces stuff in this scenario.

Comment: @goldilocks dhcpd is disabled in my raspberry I'm use ISP router dhcpd and reservation table.

Comment: a bond must be configured on both sides. What is configured at the ISP side?

Comment: I didn't set the other side, probably I misunderstood the concept. Tks for the tip